# My function takes negative time to complete. What in the world happened?

Tags: python, time, timing

I'm posing this question mostly out of curiosity. I've written some code that is doing some very time intensive work. So, before executing my workhorse function, I wrapped it up in a couple of calls to time.clock(). It looks something like this:

```
t1 = time.clock()
print this_function_takes_forever(how_long_parameter = 20)
t2 = time.clock()
print t2 - t1
```

This worked fine. My function returned correctly and `t2 - t1` gave me a result of `972.29`, or about 16 minutes.

However, when I changed my code to this

```
t1 = time.clock()
print this_function_takes_forever(how_long_parameter = 80)
t2 = time.clock()
print t2 - t1
```

My function still returned fine, but the result of `t2 - t1` was:

```
None
-1741
```

I'm curious as to what implementation detail causes this. Both the None, and the negative number are perplexing to me. Does it have something to do with a signed type? How does this explain the `None`?

Comment: You have written the worlds first time machine. Congratulations!

Comment: Do you know aboutish how long the function took ? e.g. on linux, clock() might wrap around after 72 minutes.

Comment: Maybe DST ends early in your timezone :p

Comment: @nos I am on a linux box, and the code took about an hour and 10 minutes to complete. So, right around the 72 minute mark...

Comment: It's probably not possible to tell why your function returned `None` without seeing the code. Of course presumably it's a lot of code if it takes 16 minutes to run! My guess is your function may have "fallen out" of your normal execution path, bypassing all of the return statements and thus returning `None`, which is the default. Can't do much better without code, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Wayne I've actually already found and fixed this. I was more curious about the time, but thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.clock) say:

> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function of the same name

The [manpage](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/clock) of the referenced C function then explains the issue:

> Note  that  the time can wrap around.  On a 32-bit system where CLOCKS_PER_SEC equals 1000000 this function will
>          return the same value approximately every 72 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

A quick guess... Looks like an overflow. The default data type is probably a signed data type (putting the first bit to 1 on a signed integer gives a negative number).

Try putting the result of the substraction in a variable (double), and then printing that.

If it still prints like that, you can try converting it from double to string, and then using 'print' function on the string.

Comment: Ok, I've generalized the description. The concept would be the same.

Comment: If the code snippet is running on the same system, i wouldn't see a scenario where t2 is smaller than t1. Unless python behaves completely differently.

Comment: @Wadih, no the result wont be the same, because time.clock() returns a double, unless your theory is that the underlying python or platform implementation has an overflow bug, which may well be possible, but I find it highly dubious.

Comment: it seems sth's answer is the right one. Clock() doesn't give the amount of seconds since like 1st jan 1970, it's range is limited and has a modulo of 72 minutes. voting him up

Comment: numeric types will (almost) never overflow in python. They just go Long. Try `2**10000000` and see http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OverflowError

Comment: @Wayne: `2.0**10000000`. Note that `time.clock()` returns a float.

Comment: "Because of the lack of standardization of floating point exception handling in C, most floating point operations also aren’t checked." - I suppose I was a technically incorrect combining `numeric` and `almost`. Floating points *can* overflow, but it's quite large, past `100000.0*24*60*60.0`.

Answer (score 1):

The None has a very simple answer, your function does not return a value. Actually I gather that is does under normal circumstances, but not when how_long_parameter = 80. Because your function seems to be returning early (probably because execution reaches the end of the function where there is an implicit return None in Python) the negative time might be because your function takes almost no time to complete in this case? So look for the bug in your function and correct it.

The actual answer as to why you get a negative time depends on the operating system you are using, because clock() is implemented differently on different platforms. On Windows it uses QueryPerformanceCounter(), on *nix it uses the C function clock().

Comment: You're right. On both the fact that my function doesn't return anything for that parameter, and that that was a very simple answer. Thanks.