# Timer shows negative time elapsed

Tags: python, time

I'm using a quite simple code to time each loop in a `for` statement. It looks something like this:

```
import time

for item in list_of_files:

    # Start timing this loop.
    start = time.clock()

    # Do a bunch of stuff.

    # Get time elapsed in seconds.
    elapsed = time.clock() - start

    # Get minutes and seconds.
    m, s = divmod(elapsed, 60)

    # Print result.
    print 'End of analysis for %s in %dm %02ds.\n'% (item, m, s)
```

This will most of the times result in correct outputs like `9m 52s` but sometimes with large loops (that take some time) I get negative results like `-53m 17s`.

I can't pinpoint a clear limit where results start showing as negative values but it apparently only happens for elapsed times > 20 min, but not for **every** loop that took > 20 min (ie: it's not consistent).

Is there something in my code to time each loop that's causing this?

### Add

I'm using `Spyder` as my IDE. I compared how `time.clock()` behaved vs `time.time()` and this is what I see:

```
>>> st1, st2 = time.clock(), time.time()
>>> st1,st2
(507.65, 1374502193.357196)
>>> print time.clock()-st1, time.time()-st2
0.14 15.1921429634
>>> print time.clock()-st1, time.time()-st2
0.34 35.0087578297
>>> print time.clock()-st1, time.time()-st2
0.67 69.8715758324
>>> print time.clock()-st1, time.time()-st2
0.77 80.0557789803
>>> print time.clock()-st1, time.time()-st2
1.25 130.559605837
>>> print time.clock()-st1, time.time()-st2
3.02 309.845729828
>>> print time.clock()-st1, time.time()-st2
8.9 899.936934948
```

Shouldn't `time.clock()` return the time elapsed in seconds? The `time.time()` call keeps accurate track of the elapsed time in seconds (for example, the last call is made after 15 mins had passed which equals 900 sec) but I have no idea what `time.clock()` is doing.

Comment: curious: is there any threading going on in  your `bunch of stuff`? [This is why I ask](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/introduction-to-python-profiling-1966784)

Comment: Are you working on Windows or on Linux?

Comment: Can you find a specific example?

Comment: I'm working on Linux (elementary OS actually, which is based on Ubuntu 12.04)

@inspectorG4dget give me a few minutes to check it out, I'm not familiar with threading (which probably means I'm not using it)

Comment: 1.maybe >[that is (3292865)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292865/my-function-takes-negative-time-to-complete-what-in-the-world-happened)< the cause, 2. if yes, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @JeremyBentham I can't post a specific example because the code (ie: what's hidden by `Do a bunch of stuff`) is quite large.

@Jakob: I'll check it out.

Comment: Did you try to use time.time() instead?
http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo I did not, I'll check that out too.

Comment: see also [measuring-elapsed-time-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421641/measuring-elapsed-time-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you're getting some kind of overflow.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock

The linux man page for clock suggests that the return values for clock cycle, so if happen to clock start at a high value and stop at a low value, and your difference is signed, you might get a negative value for time elapsed.

Since you're timing events that go on for multiple seconds, maybe the time.time() function would be more appropriate for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

`time.clock()` measures CPU time on Unix systems, not wall time.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/clock.html for more info on the underlying system call (note the part where it says it can wrap).

If you want to measure walltime, use `time.time()`.