# Printing time in Python multiprocessing script return negative time elapsed

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, multiprocessing

Running it on **Ubuntu 14** with **Python 2.7.6**

I simplified script to show my problem:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

data = range(1, 3)
start_time = time.clock()


def lol():
    for i in data:
        print time.clock() - start_time, "lol seconds"


def worker(n):
    print time.clock() - start_time, "multiprocesor seconds"


def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
    p.map(worker, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lol()
    mp_handler()
```

And the output:

```
8e-06 lol seconds
6.9e-05 lol seconds
-0.030019 multiprocesor seconds
-0.029907 multiprocesor seconds

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Using  `time.time()` gives non-negative values (as marked here [Timer shows negative time elapsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788724/timer-shows-negative-time-elapsed))
but I'm curious what is the problem with `time.clock()` in python `multiprocessing` and reading time from CPU.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`multiprocessing` spawns **new** processes and [`time.clock()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html#time.clock) on linux has the same meaning of the C's [`clock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock):

> The value returned is the *CPU time used so far* as a clock_t;

So the values returned by `clock` restart from `0` when a process start. However your code uses the *parent's* process `start_time` to determine the time spent in the child process, which is obviously incorrect if the child processes CPU time resets.

The `clock()` function makes sense *only* when handling **one** process, because its return value is the CPU time spent by *that* process. Child processes are *not* taken into account.

The `time()` function on the other hand uses a system-wide clock, and thus can be used even between different processes (although it is *not* monotonic, so it might return wrong results if somebody changes the system time during the events).

Forking a running python instance is probably faster then starting a new one from scratch, hence `start_time` is almost always bigger then the value returned by `time.clock()`.
Take into account that the parent process also had to read your file on disk, perform the imports which may require reading other `.py` files, searching directories etc.
The forked child processes don't have to do all that.

---

Example code that shows that the return value of `time.clock()` resets to `0`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time
import multiprocessing

data = range(1, 3)
start_time = time.clock()


def lol():
    for i in data:
        t = time.clock()
        print('t: ', t, end='\t')
        print(t - start_time, "lol seconds")


def worker(n):
    t = time.clock()
    print('t: ', t, end='\t')
    print(t - start_time, "multiprocesor seconds")


def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
    p.map(worker, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start_time', start_time)
    lol()
    mp_handler()
```

Result:

```
$python ./testing.py 
start_time 0.020721
t:  0.020779    5.8e-05 lol seconds
t:  0.020804    8.3e-05 lol seconds
t:  0.001036    -0.019685 multiprocesor seconds
t:  0.001166    -0.019555 multiprocesor seconds
```

Note how `t` is monotonic for the `lol` case while goes back to `0.001` in the other case.

Answer (score 3):

To add a concise Python 3 example to Bakuriu's excellent answer above you can use the following method to get a global timer independent of the subprocesses:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

# create iterable
iterable = range(4)

# adds three to the given element
def add_3(num):
    a = num + 3
    return a

# multiprocessing attempt
def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    results = pool.map(add_3, iterable)    
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":  #Required not to spawn deviant children    
    start=time.time()

    results = main()
    print(list(results))

    elapsed = (time.time() - start)  
    print("\n","time elapsed is :", elapsed)
```

Note that if we had instead used `time.process_time()` instead of `time.time()` we will  get an undesired result.